# No output to the Maven console in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

Somehow I do not get any log messages anymore in the Maven / m2e console view in Eclipse. This makes it difficult to see what Maven / m2e is doing.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should check is that you have the *m2e - slf4j over logback logging* plugin installed via by checking the *Plugins* tab in the *About Eclipse* dialog.

If the plugin is not there, you can install it via *Help -> Install New Software*, set *Work with* to *--All Available Sites--*, search for *m2e logback* or locate it manually in the category *Maven Integration for Eclipse*.

If this is already installed, then the problem is probably that another plugin has also installed an SLF4J backend. In this case, you can "hack" your Eclipse's plugin configuration to remove the second backend:

- Close Eclipse
- Open the file `configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info`
- Remove the line starting with `org.slf4j.impl.log4j12`
- Start Eclipse again

Source: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=520754#c2

If you are on OS X, the is located inside the `Eclipse.app` bundle in the folder `Contents/Eclipse`. On other systems, the `configuration` should be a subfolder of your Eclipse directory.

Comment: In my case, I had the same problem. After closing Eclipse, I have commented the line that starts with `org.slf4j.impl.log4j12` and I have started Eclipse without any result. But when I have uncommented that line and started Eclipse again, the Maven Console has started to show information.

Comment: @rec please, accept with answer. Accelent solution.